# How to connect powerful stepper motor to Raspberry Pi Model 3B

Tags: pi-3, pi-2

Can I connect powerful stepper motor (works under 220V) to a Raspberry Pi with GPIO, for example a [FL130BYG](http://www.directindustry.com/prod/changzhou-fulling-motor-co-ltd/product-70595-1713043.html)? What should I do to connect it?

Answer (score 2):

You control stepper motors with stepper motor driver boards.

You need to find an appropriate driver board for your stepper motor.

You also need to make sure that any driver board you choose can be controlled by 3V3 GPIO.

Comment: can you suggest any driver for this, please?

Comment: @Sergey No, it's not my field.  Usually professional steppers have links to appropriate driver boards mentioned in the literature.  Try the site you bough it from.